# Import vuejs components inside wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, vue.js

I am creating a wordpress site with vuejs framework. I am about to put vuejs components into this directory.

`wp-content/themes/{theme}/components`

The problem is, I can't import vuejs components with ES6 `import App from './components/App.vue'` functionality.

I tried using CDN but I don't know how importing of components works.

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 1):

the are 2 main solutions for this problem:

- (best): compile your project ([for example with the vue-CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/)) in such a way that all imports used in the project are compiled into simple, browser-readable js files
- use the [http-vue-loader](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/http-vue-loader) library to load components directly from the browser (this solution works perfectly, but in terms of performance with many components it is not recommended)

Comment: httpVueLoader is simple. But the problem is, it does not import vue file because it import relative to URL and not the path. The result for impot is `404`. How can I fix this?

Comment: you should configure your WordPress site to be able to expose the *.vue files to the public. your goal is to be able to see your vue components directly in the browser, for instance, www.yourdomain.com/vue-components/navbar.vue should return your navbar.vue component.